# I want the window to spin around the object, and it shows me points, edges and faces

Tags: keymap

This is a question regarding blender 3.5.1. I did not notice that there is a saving of key customization types, and messed up the first one. Tell me where to look for the key setting, I want my window to rotate around the object when I press the right mouse button. That is, these edges, points and faces to stand out Shift->right mouse click. And this is what it gives me
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into key-binding in preferences and search up middle mouse, change the keying from middle mouse to right mouse button. Then, switch to Name and then  search up object context menu and then change it to whatever works for you, or else the right mouse rotate will not work. Hope this helps.

Answer number 2 : if you set shift right mouse button then you have to change your object context menu keybind to another button or else it will override the other keybind instead.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alas, I'm still looking at the same picture. And renaming from mouse to keyboard does nothing. Still the window opens not by the specified keys, but by the mouse.

Comment: Did it. Only instead of the right mouse button, my rotation occurs due to the middle one, and the movement is through the shift of the middle mouse button.